# Add Kafka event listener after transaction committed in Springboot with Kotlin

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin, apache-kafka, avro

I have a Kafka Listener receiving avro message:

```
@Service
class MyListener(private val useCase: MyUseCase) {
    @KafkaListener(topics = ["\${app.topic}"], autoStartup = "\${app.event.auto-startup:true}")
    fun listen(message: decision_made_v1) {
        useCase.perform(message.payload)
    }
}
```

On another part of my application, there's a repository operation:

```
@Component
class CreateResource(private val myRepository: MyRepository) {
    fun execute(command: MyCommand): Resource {
        return myRepository.save(command)
    }
}
```

How can I allow my Kafka Listener to receive and call `useCase.perform` **only after** `myRepository.save` commited in db?

Comment: What is the connection between the data being committed and consuming the next message on the topic? Listener will just receive messages as they are available on the topic so unless you publish a message after commit there can't really be a relationship. As a general rule it is difficult to tie Kafka messages and DB transactions anyway because Kafka can't be involved in 2 phase commit but you can coordinate things to an extent with a few tricks.

Comment: From your description it sounds like your listen method needs to wait for some data to be persisted before processing a message, but then you would be blocking the polling thread and most likely trigger a rebalance. Can you just expand a bit on the relationship between these two aspects of your application - from what you have described it doesn't really sound like a soluble problem